# Django NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django

I am new to Django and have started working on a mature Django project.

I want to add a new page to the user account screens, and link to it. But I am getting a NoReverseMatch error.

To /users/urls.py I added:

```
url(r'^panel/history$',
    'theproject.users.views.history',
    name='account_history'
),
```

...which is consistent with the line above it:

```
url(r'^panel$',
    'theproject.users.views.control_panel',
    name='account_panel'
),
```

To /users/views.py I added:

```
@login_required
def history(request):
    return render_to_response('users/ourbrand_history.html', {},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

...which is consistent with the line above it:

```
@login_required
def control_panel(request):
    return render_to_response('users/ourbrand_panel.html', {},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

To /templates/users/ourbrand_panel.html I added:

```
<a href="{% url account_history %}">History</a>
```

...which is consistent with the line above it:

```
<a href="{% url account_panel %}">Home</a>
```

Now when I load /panel I get a TemplateSyntaxError: NoReverseMatch.

```
Reverse for 'account_history' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

UPDATE: As a test, I removed my link in the template -- and /panel loads fine. If I then delete /users/urls.py and /users/views.py /panel still loads. I have deleted all cookies, history etc. Do I have to run a command at the terminal (like rake in ruby) to commit changes to urls.py? Or should changes 'just work'?

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything looks correct (although trailing slashes are a good idea, as @pastylegs says). Is there possibly something you didn't cut/paste, some minor syntax error in another line that might be affecting it? Maybe an extra quote " or something that changes how the template reads?

Comment: And (although I presume you cut/paste the code and what is shown is correct) - you might double-check that you consistently used underscores `_` everywhere, and didn't accidently use a hyphen `-` :) I was just testing my named URLs, switching the hyphens I use for underscores (which worked). But when I mixed them, it generated the same error.

Comment: If you're running the Django development server, all file changes cause the server to reload the files, so you don't have to commit anything. However, in a template - if a variable doesn't exist, it just evaluates to an empty string, it doesn't give you any error, so the page will load fine.

Comment: Per @pastylegs' answer I did add the trailing slashes. I triple checked all the syntax: no extra quotes or hyphens instead of underscores. You said "in a template - if a variable doesn't exist...the page will load fine." If that's true, why does Django complain about not finding a reverse for `account_history` in urlpatterns?

Comment: Wups, you're right - it's not a variable like `{{ foo }}`, it's a *tag*, `{% url foo %}`. I get those mixed up. :) Something else to try, though: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`, and somewhere before the return, `print reverse('account_history')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question (based on help provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281849/changes-to-project-urls-py-ignored-by-django))...

Since the server is production, changes to `urls.py` do not have any effect until the server is restarted. Currently I do not have `su` access so cannot `apachectl restart` but it appears this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{% url users.views.control_panel %}
{% url users.views.history %}
```

in the template and change:

```
url(r'^panel/history/$','theproject.users.views.history',name='account_history'),
url(r'^panel/$','theproject.users.views.control_panel',name='account_panel'),

           ^
```

in the urls. (notice the trailing slashes in the first argument.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using mod_wsgi, then a simple:

```
$ touch /path/to/your/wsgi_file.wsgi
```

Should do the trick (without having to restart the server).

Answer (score 1):

Move this:

```
url(r'^panel/history/$',
    'theproject.users.views.history',
    name='account_history'
),
```

from the `users/urls.py` to the project level `urls.py`.

It could be that the `users/urls.py` is not linked to from the main `urls.py` that also defines a view for `/panel/`

Comment: If so, then he'd be better off doing an `include('users.urls')` in the main `urls.py`, and keeping the URL in `users/urls.py`, rather than moving the URL.

Comment: I tried this but still get the `NoReverseMatch` error. As to whether `/users/urls.py` is getting called from the main `urls.py`, I believe it is: `urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^accounts/', include('theproject.users.urls')))`