# Changes to /project/urls.py ignored by Django

Tags: django

I am starting work on a mature Django project and notice something unusual. When I edit urls.py -- whether at the project level or below -- Django ignores my changes.

Debugging is on, so when I get a 404 Django prints all the URL patterns it tried. From this I see the URL patterns from *before I made my changes*.

Again, this is regardless of whether I edit /project/urls.py or /project/sub/urls.py. To be sure, the subdirectory urls.py is being included correctly.

I am focusing on the project level urls.py, just in case.

I can make a small update to urls.py or delete all of its contents. The 404 debug info shows the old url patterns.

It is as if Django is looking at a cached version of these urls.py files. How should I proceed?

Comment: how are you running your django server? Have you tried restarting the instance?

Comment: @Adam I did try that, cleared cookies, etc. @Shawn Great reminder, I will try that.

Comment: Django's built-in server (run via the `runserver` command) automatically checks for updates to the code. With any other server (including Django's `testserver`) you need to explicitly reload the source. If you tell us how you are serving your application, as Shawn Chin says, we can offer advice on how to do so!

Comment: Delete "urls.pyc", as well. It may not help, but it won't hurt either. Python files with a "c" at the end are compiled versions of the original.

Comment: @adamnfish: Technically, runserver has a mode where it *doesn't* automatically check for updates; though, it's probably unlikely that he's actually running it under that mode.

Comment: @adamnfish How do I tell how I am serving the application?

Comment: @ryaz What URL are you using to load the page? What commands did you have type before it was possible to load the page?

Comment: @ryaz, what *are* the URLs? Looking at your other question, I don't see any regular expressions - but if you have URLs like `/foo(.*)` and `/foo/bar`, they might not be evaluating like you expected.

Comment: @John Since the server is in production, changes made to urls.py require a restart. So I have to restart apache. When the SysAdmin returns I'll ask him to `su apachectl restart` which should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By deafult, Django's development server (accessed via the `runserver` management command) will keep an eye on your code and reload itself whenever something changes. If you are using any other server (including Django's `testserver` command) this is almost certainly not the case.

Typically, a server will load the source of your application when it starts. It will need to be reloaded to get the latest copy of your code. If you are using Apache with mod_wsgi (probably the most common production server for Django applications), somewhere in your source tree you will have a wsgi application file. By convention these have a `.wsgi` extension, but it can be named anything. This file is what Apache uses to load your source and a useful feature of mod_wsgi (daemon mode only) is that touching (changing the modification date) this file is enough to force the server to erload the source code. If your application has a wsgi file you can edit, doing so and re-uploading the code should be enough. The file is likely to contain the line `application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()` or something like it - this may help you

If you do not have access or you cannot find any such file, you will need to give the updated source to the server's administrator and ask them to update and reload the source. It's tricky to give you more advice without more information - perhaps you could ask the server administrator for more information so we can be mroe helpful?

== Update ==

I've checked the response headers on the link you've provided and it looks like you are using nginx to serve the site. This may just be a load-balancer in front of another server though, so I'd still recommend asking for more info from your SysAdmin.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Evidently we're just using Nginx to serve static content so I ran `apache2ctl restart` and the urls.py changes are working now.

Comment: Excellent! Bear in mind that restarting apache will affect every website that it is serving, which may have unintended side-effects. If you find the wsgi file (which will be referenced in the apache config for this site if you are struggling to track it down) then touching it will gracefully reload just this application's source.

Comment: For Apache deployments, is best to use `$ sudo apache2ctl graceful` to reload the latest config without interfering with current visitors.

Comment: Mandx, 'graceful' restart doesn't necessarily have that affect when using mod_wsgi daemon mode.

Comment: I ran into what appeared to be the exact same problem, but the suggestions didn't work.  As it turned out, Firefox was caching a redirect from an old urls.py config and never hitting the server.  Had to clear the browser's cache.

Comment: This is working for me an an Apache WSGI server :`watch -n 1 touch wsgi.py` Performance is slow though since it's always reloading everything on each request.