# Django how to see urls.py and settings.py changes without apache restart

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess

I am setting up a django project on an apache server. I have access to the .htaccess and index.fcgi files, but no sudo access. 
When I make changes to urls.py or settings.py, the changes don´t come through. 
Is there a way to see changes come through without restarting apache? For example by adding a configuration to the .htaccess file?

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282363/5881884 is recommended doing touch on the .wsgi file, but I don´t have any file ending with .wsgi and neither is there a file including the string django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

.htaccess file:

```
 AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
 RewriteRule /static/ /home/myusername/public_html/static
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$     
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are looking for is `wsgi.py`, it should be in the same folder that `urls.py`. If you are using a modern version of Django, the file should looks like this:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yoursite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The `get_wsgi_application` function calls and return `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()`, so this is the file you should touch according to the answer in the other link.